# Apache "SSLSessionCacheTimeout" with Client Certs

Tags: apache, ssl, https, certificate

After logging onto my web app, users need to authenticate with a X.509 cert.

After a period of inactivity, a user will try to continue using the site. At that point, a new session will be attempted to be made, but fail. It fails due to the fact that re-authentication is not occurring.

If I were to increase Apache's `SSLSessionCacheTimeout` to, let's say, 8 hours , would the client no longer need to re-authenticate during session creation?

Note - assuming a new session needs to be created within the 8 hours set for the Apache `SSLSessionCacheTimeout`.

**EDIT** Or, does the SSL session not impact HTTPS sessions at all?

Comment: The SSL session renegotiation should not have any impact of the application-level session. Could you be more specific regarding what you mean by "users need to authenticate with a X.509 cert" and "a new session will be attempted to be made, but fail. It fails due to the fact that re-authentication is not occurring." ?

Comment: User first logs onto web app | selects certificate from a smart card | custom Spring Security code extracts the necessary LDAP credential | eventually gets access to web app. However, if the user's session expires, a new session cannot be created (presumably since re-authentication does not occur) and the web app crashes. I was curious if, by setting that Apache field to a higher value, if a new session could be authenticated as a result of the higher value since it would, presumably, use the client cert.

Comment: The thing is, the browser will automatically resend the X.509 certificate in case the server (not finding a match for the sessionID sent by the client) request a new session. So, apart from what happen at application-level, a new TLS session creation occuring after the  SSLSessionCacheTimeout should not differ from the first TLS session creation. Note that this does not apply if the client and the server use rfc5077 "Session Resumption without Server-Side State".

Comment: @RemiGacogne, so the `SSL session` varies from the `HTTP session`? Users authenticate via a smart card by picking the right cert. After the HTTP session expires, a new HTTP session is attempted to be established, but fails. I think it fails because it doesn't re-authenticate. I was curious if incrementing `SSLSessionCacheTimeout`  would help since, upon making a new session, the SSL cert would still be around. My thought was that the SSL cert had expired as per the `SSLSessionCacheTimeout`, but, if I extended it, the new session should be successfully created.

Comment: The SSL Session is not co-extensive with the HTTP session. Both can expire independently. Certificates don't 'expire as per the SSLSessionCacheTimeout', they have expiry times measured in years. 8 hours is far too long for an SSL session: they are usually measured in minutes. It's rather long even for an HTTP session. There is far too much guesswork here. You need to stop guessing and making assumptions, and find out what is *actually* happening. Some HTTP traces for example. Edited into the post.

Comment: @EJP, could you please let me know what I should look for with the `HTTP traces`? I admit there's guesswork, but it's out of my uncertainty.

Comment: more interesting would be to know what are you doing in your HTTP session when the SSL cert session is not valid anymore, maybe that crashes your app. think of you are a finance-bank and want to make your web-session-service safe, what should happen to the session if the cert is not valid anymore, what should the user do an what should never work in any circumstances if the cert is not valid anymore.

Comment: @codelio The HTTP session doesn't know when the SSL session expires. There is no such thing as the 'SSL cert session'. We are discussing SSL sessions expiry, not certificate expiry. The HTTP session doesn't know about certificate expiry either.

Comment: @Kevin Suppose *you* tell *us* what problem you actually have, and what evidence you have for it?

Comment: @EJP, looking at the `apache-error` logs, I see: `Re-negotiation handshake failed: Not accepted by client!?`. Looking at your answer on a ServerFault post (http://serverfault.com/questions/410925/configuring-client-certificate-authentication-in-apache), I may be using OpenSSL 0.9.8, which, according to a commentered on your answer, says has an issue with renegotiation.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Apache SSL documentation http://www.apache-ssl.org/docs.html
Look for "SSLSessionCacheTimeout" according to the documentation increasing the value of this setting should work.

Comment: Have you read the commentary? *Of course* increasing the SSL session timeout will increase the SSL session timeout, but there is no evidence in the question that this is the actual problem, and plenty of reasons not to prolong SSL sessions unduly, starting with security concerns and resource usage.

Comment: Got it, I missed the additional comments from May 7th and on.

Comment: I dont know but this solved my problem, apprently when users where accessing website from VPN sometime they where able to get to the site, increased this and no one has complained since.